# How to lighten a bitmap in Android?

Tags: android, android-bitmap, colorfilter

I'm using a set of bitmaps to draw my SurfaceView and developing a night mode. To turn on night mode I just darken all bitmaps and redraw the SurfaceView:

```
    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(newBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0x808080, 0));
    c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    bitmap = newBitmap;
```

But how can I lighten these bitmaps when I need to turn off night mode?

Comment: tried `add` param in `LightingColorFilter`?

Comment: "Add" does not match my requirement. I need to *Darken* by (r, g, b) -> (r / 2, g / 2, b / 2) and *Lighten* by (r, g, b) -> (r * 2, g * 2, b * 2), but LightingColorFilter seems unable to do multiplication :-(

Comment: so you want to darken or lighten?

Comment: darken is ok. need a solution to lighten bitmaps

Comment: so did you try `add` parameter?

Comment: not yet. how much to add?

Comment: i have no idea, you have to try

Comment: I tried `new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFF, 0x808080)` and bitmaps become greyish white :-(

Comment: the same for 0x606060, 0x404040, 0x202020 ?

Comment: a bit white, less than 0x808080

Comment: found a solution :-) `new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new float[] {
   2, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 2, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 2, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
  }));`